# Old passport has missing pages. What should I tell the Visa Officer during the visa interview?

Tags: visas, usa, passports, india, f1-visas

I am applying for US F1 visa. My old passport had some mistake in my surname. So I got a new passport two years back. I did not know that I may need my old passport during the visa interview. My sister took my old passport saying that she will play with it. When I asked the passport back I discovered she has torn down two of its pages, including the first page where they put the CANCELLED stamp. All the personal information pages are intact. Do visa officers scrutinize the old passports ? Now what should I tell the visa officer if they ask me about the missing pages ?

P.S.: My old passport did not have any visa stamp on it.

Comment: You should try to help the visa officer in reaching an informed and fair decision, be as helpful as you can. This would necessarily involve telling the full truth. And yes, they look at everything they ask for. We can't help you contrive an excuse. Close voting as 'opinion-based'

Comment: Just tell them the truth.

Answer (score 7):

Tell the visa officer the truth if they ask. If you have the torn pages, that's even better. Bring them with you to show the officer.

Overall it should have zero effect on the results of your interview. If you previously applied for a visa and were denied, be honest. Dishonesty can scuttle your hopes of obtaining the visa quicker than anything.

Comment: Note: stick it means insert them loosely in the passport. It does not mean actually *stick* them with glue/tape to the passport.

Comment: Hi.. I dont have those torn pages. Thanks for your answer.